# Solr patternreplacefilterfactory gives unmatching values

Tags: solr, highlight, tokenize, solrj, solr4

I setup a field with a type configured as

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
          <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
                 pattern="#(\w+)" replacement="HTAG.$1 $1"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
              <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory"
                 pattern="#(\w+)" replacement="HTAG.$1"/>
            <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.CommonGramsFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

My aim is to index both words and #words. So that `#usopen` will be indexed for both `usopen` and `#usopen`.

And query with the parameters in addition to `hl` factors as `hl.fl=text&hl.fragsize=0&hl.simple.pre=<tag>hl.simple.post=</tag>&hl.requireFieldMatch=true`.

When I query for `usopen`, highlighting text value shown as `#usope<tag>n</tag>` and when querying for `#usopen`, the text value shown as `<tag>usope</tag>n`.

Whats the issue in above configuration and help me to fix it.

Comment: CharFilter cannot go after tokenization. It has to be first. CharFilter/Tokenizer/Filter.

Comment: I setup the field with the same order as you specified. The issue is with highlighting. Updated the qn.

Answer (score 0):

The CharFilter is most likely changes the offsets in the indexed string that then do not match original.

Try using TokenFilter instead (PatternReplaceFilterFactory).

Also, it may make more sense to just normalize #something=>something both during indexing and searching and not try keeping both forms. As long as it matches, it is all you care about.

Comment: But I need to index keyword along with hashtag. Any other solution exists?

Comment: Why do you need to index the hashtag version? The indexed representation is only there to make search happen. Users do not normally see it (exception is faceting).

Comment: to support hashtag search. I am trying to index tweets and exact search of any hashtag events

Comment: Then try something like PatternCaptureGroupFilterFactory